# How I can install this package "JohnsonDistribution"

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to install this removed package in R, but I cannot. Any idea?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JohnsonDistribution/index.html

The code that I used is the next:

```
install.packages("~/R/win-library/3.5/johnson.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

And the error:

```
 Warning in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'johnson/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :  no se puede abrir la conexión
In R CMD INSTALL 
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Angel/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/johnson.zip’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thanks,

PD: I not asking how I can install in other way, I'm asking how I can install this specific package that gives me an error

Comment: Have you tried the following in RStudio: tools menu -> install packages; in the "install from" drop down, select "Package Archive" then choose the .tar.gz file that's downloaded locally?

Comment: yes, i have try this

Comment: maybe `devtools::install_version("JohnsonDistribution", version="0.24")`: but you will need compilers installed!

Answer (score 1):

Using the URL provided, you can install directly with the following:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz", 
             repos = NULL)
```

The following should occur

```
> install.packages("https://cran.r-    project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz", 
+                  repos = NULL)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-    project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.2    4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7744 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 7744 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘JohnsonDistribution’ ...
** package ‘JohnsonDistribution’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c JohnsonCurve.f -o JohnsonCurve.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined     dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -    L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o     JohnsonDistribution.so JohnsonCurve.o -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-    apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -    F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -    Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-    L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
installing to     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/JohnsonDistribution/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (JohnsonDistribution)
```

Comment: I've the next error:
`install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz", 
             repos = NULL)`

Comment: @AngelPrieto : sorry can you please explain? What error do you get? I will edit my answer to show you what happens when I run this code.

Comment: ** package 'JohnsonDistribution' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'JohnsonDistribution'
* removing 'C:/Users/Angel/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/JohnsonDistribution'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Angel/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/JohnsonDistribution'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Angel/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgbP2kz/downloaded_packages/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: i've anwer with the error. Thanks

Comment: @AngelPrieto : try install.packages("devtools")  then library(devtools)  and try running the code again.

Answer (score 0):

ZIP is not the standard package format. Use the tarball (*.tar.gz) available on CRAN:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz

```
path_to_file = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz"
install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

---

Alternatively, if you absolutely need to use that ZIP file, you can repack it from within R, and then use the command above to install the resulting TAR:

```
unzip("~/R/win-library/3.5/johnson.zip")
shell("R CMD build johnson")
```

Comment: I've the next error: `I've the next error:
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/JohnsonDistribution/JohnsonDistribution_0.24.tar.gz", 
             repos = NULL)`